# Finding the slope of a tangent line to a polar curve at given points

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I am given the following polar curve and set of points:

$r^2$ = 9cos(2$\theta$)

$(0, \frac{\pi}{4})$

$ (0,-\frac{\pi}{4})
$

I need to find the slope of the line tangent to that curve at the given points. The textbook has had me solve many of these problems for equations of the form $r = a sin(\theta)$, but not for $r^2$.

My professor suggested that I pursue implicit differentiation. So by taking $\frac{d}{d\theta}$ of both sides, I get:

$
2r * \frac{dr}{d\theta} = \frac{d}{d\theta} 9cos(2\theta)
$

$
2r * \frac{dr}{d\theta} = -18sin(2\theta)
$

$
\frac{dr}{d\theta} = \frac{-9sin(2\theta)}{r}
$

The formula provided by my textbook that I am to use now is:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{f'(\theta)sin(\theta) + f(\theta)cos(\theta)}{f'(\theta)cos(\theta) -f(\theta)sin(\theta)}
$

Given that $f(\theta)=r$, I assume that $f'(\theta)$ = $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$; but what do I plug in for $f(\theta)$? $
 f(\theta) =r= \frac{-9sin(2\theta)}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}}?$ $ f(\theta) = \pm\sqrt{9cos(2\theta)}$?

Regardless, I can't plug in the given points into $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$, because $r=0$ in both points, so that would give me some undefined value. But if you look at the graph, the slopes at those points are 1 and -1.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} =\frac{d(r\sin\theta)}{d(r\cos\theta)} = \frac{\sin\theta dr + r\cos\theta d\theta}{\cos\theta dr - r\sin\theta d\theta} = \frac{\sin\theta \frac{dr}{d\theta} + r\cos\theta}{\cos\theta \frac{dr}{d\theta}-r\sin\theta}.\ \ \   (1)$$

From $r=\pm 3\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}$, one has $\frac{dr}{d\theta} = \mp 3\frac{\sin 2\theta}{\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}}$.

Substitute in (1), one has $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-3\sin\theta \frac{\sin 2\theta}{\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}}+3\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}\cos\theta}{-3\cos\theta \frac{\sin 2\theta}{\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}}-3\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}\sin\theta} = \frac{-\cos 3\theta}{\sin 3\theta}$$

So, at $(r,\theta) = (0,\frac{\pi}{4})$, or $(x,y) = (0,0)$, slope of tangent line is $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\cot \frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks for the response: a few questions though:

Comment: 1) Is your $\mp$ different from $\pm$ in some way? I have never seen that symbol before. Also, how do you reconcile the fact that your $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ has a plus or minus sign, but when you substitute it into (1) you only use the negative version of it?

Comment: 2) On top of that, when you plugged in $r$, you used the positive version. I see that $-cot\frac{3\pi}{4}$ is the answer, but I'm not sure why you chose the positive version of $r$ and the negative version of $dr$, or more generally, why it works mathematically to choose one or the other.

Comment: Sorry about late reply. When you substitute $r$ to (1), you will see that $r$ and $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ is not same sign: $r$ is positive then $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ is negative, and vice-versa. So, I used notation $\mp$ to say that. Is it clear? Now, the answer of second question is simple. You will get the same result when you substitue $(r, \frac{dr}{d\theta})$ in (1). Please check that.

Comment: FYI, we have the equation of this curve in $(x,y)$-coordinates is $9(x^2-y^2) = (x^2+y^2)^2$. And you can see that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is symmetric with $y$. So, two tangent lines are parallel, so the slope is the same.

Comment: Thanks - that definitely clears things up for me!